# Why '===' is slower than comparing char by char when comparing two string in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, string, performance

I found that in **Nodejs** comparing two strings by comparing every char of them is faster than using the statement 'str1 === str2'.
What is the reason for this? And in **browsers**, it's just opposite.

Here is the code that I had tried, the two long strings are equal.Node version is **v8.11.3**

```js
function createConstantStr(len) {
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode((i % 54) + 68);
  }

  return str;
}

let str = createConstantStr(1000000);
let str2 = createConstantStr(1000000);

console.time('equal')
console.log(str === str2);
console.timeEnd('equal')

console.time('equal by char')
let flag = true;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] !== str2[i]) {
    flag = false;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(flag);
console.timeEnd('equal by char');
```

Comment: I am not seeing the same speed improvement as you are - in fact, I have quite the opposite:

true
equal: 23.945ms
true
equal by char: 124.190ms

Comment: If I run the snippet, equal by === took 23 ms while equal by char took 123.165ms

Comment: I got equal: 34.335ms and equal by char: 79.300ms

Comment: @emix This is certainly not a duplicate. Have you even read the question?

Comment: I guess this is browser dependant

Comment: Its the opposite for me, comparing every char separately is slower.

Comment: Firefox ... 21 and 5 ... chrome 17 and 104 ... so chrome has rubbish loop speed (in the global scope) - if the for loop is inside a function ... it's 17 and 10 ...

Comment: For a test like this don't do a single `console.time`. Do something with (a bit) more statistical significance, like JSPerf test: https://jsperf.com/string-comparison-whole-by-char/1. You'll see that `str1 === str2` (that is, your "equal") is always faster, and way way faster.

Comment: so, umm I reversed the comparision (added another snippet), and looks like `0 ms` on `===` (firefox). So probably something to do with compiler internals trying to optimize

Comment: @idmean yes I read both the question and the proposed duplicate. One can easily draw a conclusion by reading it why the operator should be slower.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tested it in **nodejs**, not in browsers, sorry my mistake. Please try again

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's been already pointed out to you that if you flip your two tests around then comparing with `===` will be faster than comparing char by char. The explanations you've gotten so far as to why have not precisely circumscribed why that is. There are a few issues that affect your results.

## The first `console.log` call is expensive

If I try this:

```
console.time("a");
console.log(1 + 2);
console.timeEnd("a");

console.time("b");
console.log("foo");
console.timeEnd("b");
```

I get something like:

```
3
a: 3.864ms
foo
b: 0.050ms
```

If I flip code around so that I have this:

```
console.time("b");
console.log("foo");
console.timeEnd("b");

console.time("a");
console.log(1 + 2);
console.timeEnd("a");
```

Then I get something like this:

```
foo
b: 3.538ms
3
a: 0.330ms
```

If I modify the code by adding a `console.log` before any timing is taken, like this:

```
console.log("start");

console.time("a");
console.log(1 + 2);
console.timeEnd("a");

console.time("b");
console.log("foo");
console.timeEnd("b");
```

Then I get something like:

```
start
3
a: 0.422ms
foo
b: 0.027ms
```

By putting a `console.log` before starting the timings, I'm excluding the initial cost of calling `console.log` from the timings.

The way you have set up your test, the first `console.log` call is done by which ever of the `===` or char-by-char test comes first and this the cost of the first `console.log` call is added to that test. Whichever test comes second does not bear that cost. Ultimately, for a test like this, I'd rather move `console.log` outside the region that is being timed. For instance the first timed region could be written like this:

```
console.time('equal');
const result1 = str === str2;
console.timeEnd('equal');
console.log(result1);
```

Storing the result in `result1` and then using `console.log(result1)` outside the timed region ensures that you can see the result while at the same time not counting the cost incurred by `console.log`.

## Whichever of your tests comes first bears the cost of flattening the string trees internally created by v8

Node uses the v8 JavaScript engine for running your JavaScript. v8 implements a string in multiple ways. `objects.h` shows in a comment the class hierarchy that v8 supports. Here is the [section relevant to strings](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects.h#L107-L124):

```
//       - String
//         - SeqString
//           - SeqOneByteString
//           - SeqTwoByteString
//         - SlicedString
//         - ConsString
//         - ThinString
//         - ExternalString
//           - ExternalOneByteString
//           - ExternalTwoByteString
//         - InternalizedString
//           - SeqInternalizedString
//             - SeqOneByteInternalizedString
//             - SeqTwoByteInternalizedString
//           - ConsInternalizedString
//           - ExternalInternalizedString
//             - ExternalOneByteInternalizedString
//             - ExternalTwoByteInternalizedString
```

There are two classes important for our discussion: `SeqString` and `ConsString`. They differ in how they store the string in memory. The [`SeqString` class](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects/string.h#L452) is a straightforward implementation: the string is simply an array of characters. (Actually `SeqString` itself is abstract. The real classes are `SeqOneByteString` and `SeqTwoByteString` but that's not important here.) [`ConsString`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects/string.h#L564) however stores a string as a binary tree. A `ConcString` has a `first` field and a `second` field which are pointers to other strings.

Consider this code:

```
let str = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  str += i;
}
console.log(str);
```

If v8 used `SeqString` to implement the code above, then:

- At iteration 0, it would have to allocate a new string of size 1, copy to it the old value of `str` (`""`) and append to that `"0"` and set `str` to the new string (`"0"`).
- At iteration 1, it would have to allocate a new string of size 2, copy to it the old value of `str` (`"0"`) and append to that `"1"`) and set `str` to the new string (`"01"`).
- ...
- At iteration 9, it would have to allocate a new string of size 10, copy to it the old value of `str` (`"012345678"`) and append to that `"9"` and set `str` to the new string (`"0123456789"`).

The total number of characters copied for the 10 steps is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55 characters. 55 characters moved around for a string that in the end contains 10 characters.

Instead v8 actually uses `ConsString` like this:

- At iteration 0, allocate a new `ConcString` with `first` set to the old value of `str`, and `second` set to `i` (as a string) `0`, and set `str` to this new `ConcString` that was just allocated.
- At iteration 1, allocate a new `ConcString` with `first` set to the old value of `str`, and `second` set to `"1"`, and set `str` to this new `ConcString` that was just allocated.
- ...
- At iteration 9, allocate a new `ConcString` with `first` set to the old value of `str`, and `second` set to `"9"`.

If we represent each `ConcString` as `(<first>, <second>)` where `<first>` is the contents of its `first` field and `<second>` is the content of the `second` field, then the end result is this:

```
(((((((((("", "0"), "1"), "2"), "3"), "4"), "5"), "6"), "7"), "8"), "9")
```

By doing things this way v8 avoids having to copy strings over and over again from step to step. Each step is just one allocation and adjusting a couple of pointers. While storing strings as a tree helps make concatenations fast, it has a downside in that other operations become slower. v8 mitigates this by [flattening](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects/string-inl.h#L305) `ConsString` trees. After flattening the example above, it becomes:

```
("0123456789", "")
```

Note that when a `ConsString` is flattened, *this very `ConsString` object is mutated*. (From the standpoint of the JS code, the string remains the same. Only its internal v8 representation has changed.)
It is easier to compare flattened `ConsString` trees, and indeed this is exactly what v8 does ([ref](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects/string-inl.h#L290-L296)):

```
bool String::Equals(Isolate* isolate, Handle<String> one, Handle<String> two) {
  if (one.is_identical_to(two)) return true;
  if (one->IsInternalizedString() && two->IsInternalizedString()) {
    return false;
  }
  return SlowEquals(isolate, one, two);
}
```

The strings we're talking about are not internalized so `SlowEquals` is called ([ref](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/e483fb2731c13e811783bbb4bd2a70272027c15b/src/objects/string.cc#L779)):

```
bool String::SlowEquals(Isolate* isolate, Handle<String> one,
                        Handle<String> two) {
[... some shortcuts are attempted ...]
  one = String::Flatten(isolate, one);
  two = String::Flatten(isolate, two);
```

I've shown here that comparing strings for equality flattens them internally, but calls to `String::Flatten` are found in many other places. Both of your tests end up flattening the strings, through different means.

For your code, the upshot is this:

1. Your `createConstantStr` creates strings which are internally stored as a `ConsString`. So `str` and `str2` are `ConsString` objects, as far as v8 is concerned.
2. The first test you run causes `str` and `str2` to be flattened so: a) this test has to carry the cost of flattening the strings, b) the second test benefits from working with `ConcString` objects that are already flattened. (Remember, when a `ConcString` object is flattened, *this very object is mutated*. So if it is accessed again later, it is already flattened.)

Comment: Cool ! That's very detailed and underlying, I learned much more beyond the problem itself !

Comment: the `first console.log call is expensive` theory doesn't check out, with this code http://paste.debian.net/plain/1083758 , whichever test is first is still much faster. both on chrome 74.0.3729.131 and firefox 60.6.3esr

Comment: @hanshenrik I did my tests in Node. This explains the OP's timings because the OP is using Node. In Node, the internals of `console` are initialized lazily. [See here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/6bfde6a81d81e1a78aee5f14e9cd5ee2b3e0cf13/lib/internal/console/constructor.js#L141) the input and output streams are defined as getters which don't fetch their stream from `process` until needed (when that function is called, `object` is bound to the `process` global). `process` itself also initializes its streams lazily. Chrome and Firefox most likely initialize `console` eagerly.

Comment: @Louis just tested in Node version 10.15.3, even with pre-initializing console.log, the second test is still much faster: https://i.imgur.com/KRL2ZGS.png  (running the test function linked above)

Comment: @hanshenrik The console initialization is *a* factor, but not the *only* factor which explains why the OP got a `===` timing which is worse than the char-by-char comparison. Sure, if you fix that, you've not fixed everything. If it were the only factor, I would not have pointed out that the cost of flattening `ConcString` is borne by the first test.

Comment: It was too obvious that issue is console.log. so i almost closed this question and wanted to put minus. But details about internal String implementation in v8 deserves separate topic!

Answer (score 4):

I reversed the comparison operation and looks like `0 ms` (sometimes 1 ms) on `===` (firefox). So probably something to do with compiler internals trying to optimize. Something like, hey the `strings` are the same in the second comparison operation and I've already compared them. So I'll re-use the result.

This youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0ek4vV7nEA) explains best.

```js
function createConstantStr(len) {
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode((i % 54) + 68);
  }

  return str;
}

let str = createConstantStr(1000000);
let str2 = createConstantStr(1000000);

console.time('equal by char')
let flag = true;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] !== str2[i]) {
    flag = false;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(flag);
console.timeEnd('equal by char');

console.time('equal')
console.log(str === str2);
console.timeEnd('equal')
```

Comment: The JIT optimizer probably replaces the loop with an internal version `===` and since it is easily proved that `str` and `str2` are not modified in between the comparisons, it can replace the second comparison with a true literal.

Comment: @idmean exactly. The linked video provides some insight about the optimization you described

Comment: @idmean forgot to mention that I tested it in nodejs, not in browsers, sorry my mistake. Please try again

Comment: @YDSS same result, why do you think it'll be different?

Comment: OP specifically said that the problem is present in NodeJS but not in browsers, you should try debugging it in NodeJS then

Comment: what version of firefox? in my tests with firefox 60.6.3esr (64-bit), === is about 28-31 milliseconds and by char is about 3-6 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

(credits to TheWild at irc://irc.freenode.net/##Javascript for figuring it out)

at least in Firefox and Chrome and Node, str and str2 is [lazy-initialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), the actual createConstantStr() call is ran when the result is actually needed, not when you tell js to create it. if you change it to

```
let str = createConstantStr(1000000);
let str2 = createConstantStr(1000000);
console.log(str[10],str2[20]);
```

then the strings will be created in the console.log() call, and you'll get more sane results in your benchmarks, and `===` will indeed be faster. (*much* faster on my laptop, from 5ms by-char to <1 ms with ===)

---

original message:

i don't have an answer but i just want to add that i can reproduce it in firefox 60.6.3esr (64-bit), === is about 28-31 milliseconds and by char is about 3-6 milliseconds:

```
function test(){
let createConstantStr=function(len) {
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    str += String.fromCharCode((i % 54) + 68);
  }

  return str;
};

let str = createConstantStr(1000000);
let str2 = createConstantStr(1000000);

console.time('equal')
console.log(str === str2);
console.timeEnd('equal')

console.time('equal by char')
let flag = true;
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i] !== str2[i]) {
    flag = false;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(flag);
console.timeEnd('equal by char');
};
```

firefox results:

```
test();
equal: 28ms
equal by char: 6ms
undefined
test();
equal: 29ms
equal by char: 4ms
undefined
test();
equal: 29ms
equal by char: 3ms
undefined
test();
equal: 31ms
equal by char: 5ms
undefined
test();
equal: 28ms
equal by char: 4ms
undefined
```

and i can reproduce it in

```
Google Chrome   74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision    518a41c1fa7ce1c8bb5e22346e82e42b4d76a96f-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#954}
JavaScript  V8 7.4.288.26
```

chrome results:

```
test();
true
equal: 23.493896484375ms
true
equal by char: 11.197021484375ms
undefined
test();
true
equal: 22.749755859375ms
true
equal by char: 11.500244140625ms
undefined
test();
true
equal: 24.43505859375ms
true
equal by char: 11.48291015625ms
undefined
test();
true
equal: 23.84521484375ms
true
equal by char: 11.38720703125ms
undefined
test();
true
equal: 21.8798828125ms
true
equal by char: 11.0390625ms
undefined
test();
true
equal: 23.989013671875ms
true
equal by char: 10.934814453125ms
undefined
```

- laptop rolling Intel Core i7 6700 and 1200MHz ram, not running on battery.

Comment: You still don't get compiler optimization. run `equal` test after the `equal by char` (in short reverse the test) and see the result

Comment: @1556089774 turns out the actual problem is that str/str2 is being lazy-initialized, the createConstantStr() functions are not actually being executed until their return value is actually needed! that's why the first test, whichever one it is, appears to be much slower

Comment: I don't think the strings are lazily initialized at all. I cut and pasted a portion of the code you show in your answer and added timing calls before and after it. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mw0s8ac/) with what I'm running. If I run it as-is, it takes roughly 70ms. If I multiply the count by 10, it takes about 10 times longer. If lazy initialization was involved, then it should take the same time irrespective of the count passed to `createConstantStr`. This is on Chrome 73.

Comment: @Louis that result isn't proving that lazy initialization is not taking place, but it is proving that dead code elimination is *not* taking place =/ (i suppose it is initialized in the variable destructor? although that sounds stupid )

Comment: @Louis yes it is - createConstantStr has 0 side effects and the return value isn't being used. the call is dead code that could have been eliminated for performance.

Comment: @hanshenrik I see what you're saying, but it's neither here nor there. Store the return value in a variable and you'll get the same result. Add a line that says `window.foo = 1`, and you'll get the same result.